# Why cant i NAT to a local network address on my UBNT edgerouter

Tags: routing, nat, ip-forwarding-table

I am trying to set up a very simple network.

I have an Ubiquiti Edgerouter on 192.168.1.1 with eth0 as WAN port.
I also have an Ubiquiti Rocket m5 on 192.168.1.2, both the router and the Rocket have a web interface. I have set the https-port from the router on port 8443. The Rocket has a web interface on port 80 & 443.

What i did:
I have made a working connection with my router, both ssh and web interface on 8443.
Add a firewall rule for both port 80 and 443.
[image: Firewall Wan_local]

This seems to be working.
I also made a NAT rule to forward to the Rocket on 192.168.1.2
1 for port 80 and 1 for port 443.
Like so:
[image: Nat rule]

As you can see, the "count" is still 0. So i'm assuming this is the problem.

Could anyone help me here? I'm looking for a very simple way to forward to 192.168.1.2. I am quite sure the web interface is enabled, because, if i "join" the network by plugging a cable directly into the router and into my PC, i can access the web interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may seem a little counter-intuitive, but you need to change the "Translations" IP address to 192.168.1.2 and remove the IP address from the "Dest Address" field.

What the configuration is actually telling the device is that when you receive traffic with destination address/port on this interface, translate it to the translation address/port.

The purpose of this is in cases where someone may have additional external IP addresses that they are given by their provider and you may want to be doing NAT translationns.